# watch dog bite, how to get the call stack?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, watchdog

In ARM-linux, when the periodical watch dog bark is not serviced, it leads to watch dog bite i.e,a kernel panic.

So, when WD Bites, is there any way to debug or know what exactly was the call stack, which was stuck with cpu0?

Comment: *What* watch dog? Usually it's a hardware timer that generates a hardware reset.

Comment: Yes. Just a watch dog., but when it resets just want to know the reason. Is it possible checking the callstack where there was a stuck up in cpu0?

Comment: That depends on the hardware.

Comment: Many hardware watchdogs have the option to reset the CPU or to cause an interrupt.  If interrupts are supported, you could use [`dump_stack()`.](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/printk.h#n233)